# What class is the language $(C,(v_i)_{i=1}^m,x)$ complete to s.t. $C(x)$ is a boolean circuit with $m$ gates with values $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m$

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, circuits

Given the following language:
$$
L=\left\{\,(\,C,\,\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m, \,x\,) \enspace :\enspace \substack{C(x) \text{ is a boolean circuit with } m  \text{ gates}  \\i\text{'th gate value is } v_i \text{ on input } x} \right\}
$$
I need to find out to what known class $L$ is **complete** to with respect to *logspace* reductions.

I think that it is impossible to reduce $\text{CVAL}$ to $L$ because if we can compute gate's values $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m$'s we could solve $\mathrm{CVAL}$ in logspace which would imply  $\mathbf{P = LOG}$.

I also think that $L\in\mathbf{P}$ because we can calculate $C(x)$ and of course all the gates $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m$ using BFS as in computing every boolean circuit value.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Your language does seem to be in logspace.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you, Yuval. Already noticed that. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language $L$ is $\mathbf{LOG}$-complete.

All we need to check is for each gate, its value (from the $(v_i)_{i=1}^{m}$ input) is consistent with its connected gates (i.e. children).

In other words, just iterate all the gates and make sure the $(v_i)_{i=1}^{m}$'s are consistent.

This can be done in *logspace* because we just need to hold the pointer to the gate we are currently checking.

$L$ is complete because every language in *logspace* is complete.